# How to copy directory to destination that destination have same link name with source directory's name?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, cp

I have a problem. When i copy a folder to destination for that  destination has link with source folder name, the link change to directory

```
$cd /home/srr7
$mkdir jetty_home123 
$ln -s jetty_home123 jetty
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 srr7 srr7   13 Nov 27 14:12 jetty -> jetty_home123
drwxrwxr-x 2 srr7 srr7 4096 Nov 27 14:12 jetty_home123

$cp -rf /opt/jetty /home/srr7
```

/opt/jetty is directory and contain multiple files.

I want to keep jetty link and copy subfolder and files of /opt/jetty to /home/srr7/jetty/.

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to keep `jetty` link and copy subfolder and files of `/opt/jetty` to `/home/srr7/jetty/`

Do exactly what you say:

```
cp -r /opt/jetty/* /home/srr7/jetty/
```

where `/opt/jetty/*` resolves to "subfolder(s) and files of `/opt/jetty`".

Note:

- `/opt/jetty/*` won't yield hidden directories or files, so they won't be copied.

Possible failure scenarios:

- if `/opt/jetty/` contains no non-hidden directories/files at all;
- if `/opt/jetty/` contains so many directories/files, so you get [argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551).

Comment: Thanks. If there are many directory in /opt/ and many link in /home/srr7 and they are same name, i must run cp for each directory. Would you give me a one command for copy all directory in /opt/ to /home/srr7/ if link exist just copy contain of source directory to link?

Comment: @srr7 Please take our quick [tour] to learn Super User is not a forum. If you have additional requirements, they should be edited into the question body. Please note in general you shouldn't significantly change requirements after one or more answers are posted. Your question mentioned "a folder" and my answer fits; now you're talking about "one command to copy all directories". *Maybe* `rsync` can do this. If you change the question too much and my answer no longer applies, I will just delete it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I think `rsync ` solution is good answer for my problem